# ArrayAdapter contains an object based on a value

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` and `ListView` adapter. I am adding objects to the adapter but I only want to add one row with an object that contains a certain `String`. This is my code but it does not work:

```
public static List<FriendsVideoLVModel> list = new ArrayList<FriendsVideoLVModel>();

    @Override
public void add(FriendsVideoLVModel obj) {
    super.add(obj);

   for (int i=0; i <list.size(); i++) {
       if (!obj.eventTitle.equals(list.get(i).eventTitle)) {
           list.add(obj);
           notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   }
}
```

Please help. The logic looks fine to me but it just does not work. Nothing is in fact added.

Comment: have you tried after removing `super.add(obj);` ?

Comment: yeah, does nothing. why would that do anything either way?

Comment: @MaxKleine when you say *"contains a certain String"* do you mean *"equals a certain String"*? Also, if you're intending to check if an object *"contains a certain String"*, then why do you negate the result of the `String#equals` method?

Comment: @MaxKleine, For first time, list contains 0 elements, so loop will not go inside for loop, only, thats why, nothing is added..t