# Delete duplicates in arraylist

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter with a custom object. The ListView contains headers. I loop through to get the header names on my custom objects. Some of them have the SAME value for headerTitle. I do NOT want them to get added to the row if that header already exists. This is my code (in my ArrayAdapter) to try and see if the same header has been added but it does absolutely nothing:

```
public static List<FriendsVideoLVModel> list = new ArrayList<FriendsVideoLVModel>();

@Override 
public void add(FriendsVideoLVModel obj) {
    super.add(obj);
     for (int i=0; i <list.size(); i++) {
        if (!obj.eventTitle.equals(list.get(i).eventTitle)) {
            list.add(obj);
            notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: you can either check if an element with that eventTitle already exits or use a collection that remove duplicates

Comment: improve code formatting, please

Comment: Is "eventTitle" a property of the class "FriendsVideoLVModel"?

Comment: I see your list is `public static`, could it be possible that through `super.add(obj);` all your items are added to the same list, from another class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a no-duplicate List implementation out there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268672/is-there-a-no-duplicate-list-implementation-out-there)

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without more information about the class this method appears in. I can see that the logic of your `for` loop is incorrect. At the moment it looks like it might add `obj` to `list` multiple times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArrayAdapter contains an object based on a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825038/arrayadapter-contains-an-object-based-on-a-value)